# is it possible to start the Rails console from within your code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, console

I know of the ruby gem "ruby-debug" that allows you to place a **debugger** call inside your code. Using it, it's possible to have breakpoints in your code.

I used **script/console** a bit for some tests, and I would like to know if I can call it from my code.

Thanks !

EDIT:

here is some sample ruby code

```
require "ruby-debug"

[1,2,3,4,5].each do |item|
   if item == 2
      # this starts a irb-like shell from which you can step through your code
      debugger 
   end
end
```

I would like to achieve the same thing, but using the rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way is by adding **debugger** statements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst debugging you can type `irb` to open the console.  Other than that, I'm not sure I understand what you mean...